# Cannot use the constants set in my php.ini file

Tags: php, session, constants

NOTE: According to my call to phpinfo, I am working in PHP 7.4.6 on Linux witth an Apache2 handler.
That same call verifies that a bunch of constants are set:  precision, session.cookie_lifetime,
odbc.max_persistent   and many others.

In my code, though, if I say:

```
echo precision;
```

or

```
echo session.cookie_lifetime;
```

Instead of their value, I get warnings.  The last line above generates 2 warnings:

**Warning:** Use of undefined constant session - assumed 'session' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /srv/www/htdocs/secure/docs/shine/pledgedrive/inc-common.php on line 10

**Warning:** Use of undefined constant cookie_lifetime - assumed 'cookie_lifetime' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /srv/www/htdocs/secure/docs/shine/pledgedrive/inc-common.php on line 10

My question is: "What am I doing wrong?" or "Why am I not able to ask for these constants?" or "Is there a new way I need to ask for them?"

Comment: You sure you're not looking for `ini_get('precision')` or similar? I dont think any values in the ini can be directly accessed as constants at runtime

Comment: @WesleySmith  Yes, thanks, that's the problem.  I inherited some code that had this error, and I thought they knew what they were doing.  It's my first exposure to trying to use these configuration constants in a program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you wanna getting an ini parameter from php. but you call your ini names as constants. the way you wanna use is for php constants that do not have any relevance to your problem

the way you using is for this sample:

```
<?php

// pre defined constant sample
echo PHP_VERSION;

// custome constant sample
define('precision', 'Very high');
echo precision; // printing your name "Very high"

?>
```

but for your need, you should use "ini_get" function.

at first define your ini parameter in your ini file:

```
precision = "Very high"
```

and at last use "ini_get" for getting it:

```
echo ini_get('precision');
```

and you can use "ini_set" for setting existing parameters in your ini.

*****Note*****: you can't set non-exists parameters in ini with "ini_set"

Comment: Thank you!  The short answer, then, is: "These are not global constants you can just use by name.  You have to use the ini_get(), ini_set(), etc. functions to access them."  (And then the PHP Manual has lots of info once I looked those functions up.)

Comment: you're right Mark, the short answer was that you said, and i tried to explain to you difference between ini parameters and constants, not just solving your problem. as olders said: i teached you fishing, not giving you a single fish